# Appcelerator Tableview Searchbar reset

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I've created a tableview with a few rows with buttons on them.

When I use the searchbar to filter the table and press one of the buttons of the remaining rows, the entire search/filter resets... Is there any way to prevent this?

I want to keep the filter on the tableview until I reset/clear the searchbar manually and not when I click on the tableview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just had to set hideSearchOnSelection to false :)